# Second time child component is not called

Tags: angular

I have many buttons. when I click on anyone, it sets taskId in a method. and calls child component ( means change showDetailComponentto bit to true).

```
<div *ngIf='showDetailComponent'>
      <app-taskdetail [id]='myVal'></app-taskdetail>
</div>
```

when I click on any button for the first time it works but on clicking on any other button, data of child component not get updated (means child component is not called.)

Comment: You need to add more code into your question

Comment: can you show your child component code?

Comment: what should be updated? `showDetailComponent` is false, the first button you click changes it to true and that's it. I don't understand the problem...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div *ngIf='showDetailComponent'>
      <app-taskdetail [id]='myVal'></app-taskdetail>
</div>
```

The Child component is not updated because the component is already rendered to the dom,
It works for the first time because you blocked the child component with an ngIf, meaning when you click the button for the first time, the boolean value becomes true, and therefore the child component got rendered.

For the value to be updated after every button click, you need to set the boolean value to false, this will remove the component from the dom and then set the value back to true.

This will make the value updated again.

```
public updateValue() {
this.showDetailComponent = false;
setTimeout(() => {
this.myVal = valNeeded;
// set all the values..
this.showDetailComponent = true;
}, 10);}
```

Comment: Really appreciate. Thanks, it worked. but plz tell me how can setTimeout method fixed it. without it it wont work, even if i set  this.showDetailComponent = false;

Comment: may I know why we need setTimeout?

Comment: It's just a form of delay, because if we set the value  of showDetailComponent to false and want to immidiately set the value to true, we would get an error, therefore the setTimeout help to cause a delay, 10miliseconds between the time the value is set to false and true.

Answer (score 1):

@Lekens is correct but if the purpose is to update the child component, I think there are better ways to do so.

1. Pass input to the child component, which will watch any changes on that input

```js
@Input() myVal: string;

    ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
        this.doSomething(changes.myVal.currentValue);
    }
```

2. Use a subject via shared service to communicate between components

Comment: yes I can see that from your code, but what I suggested is to use ngOnChanges to know when your initial input has changed

Comment: yes, that's a better way. I was doing like this.  
  @Input() id: number;
  ngOnInit() {
    this.taskId = this.id;
    this.onRowSelect();
  }